# How to fix arrow function in React.js to work with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, react-props

I'm trying to get a simple webpage to open up on localhost:3000, and am working with React.js - currently it appears that using React.js, it is not recognising my arrow function when I type is '=>' and I've checked with a tutorial I'm following to ensure I haven't made any typos - has anybody else encountered issues with React.js and arrow functions?

Interestingly, it works just fine in the tutorial I'm watching,

Many thanks in advance!

Rechecked code, checked App.js, googled arrow function errors in React.js

Greet.js code below:

```
import React from 'react'

// function Greet() {
//     return <h1>Hey Henry!</h1>
// }

const Greet = props () => {
    console.log(props)
    return <h1>Aloha you nutter! How's it going {props.name}?</h1>}

export default Greet
```

App.js code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Greet from './components/Greet'
import Hello from './components/Hello'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {/*<header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            HELLO WORLD!!!
            Henry's first React program!
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
    </header>*/}
      <Greet name="Henry" />
      <Greet name="Adrian" />
      <Greet name="Lordi" /> 
      {/*<Hello />*/}


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Expected result:

Webpage displays on localhost:3000 displaying "Aloha you nutter! How's it going {name property goes here}?" 3 times with 3 different names.

[image: Error message on localhost:3000]

Comment: Have a look at MDN to learn about the syntax of error functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: please check your syntax in Greet.js file. Either put 'props' inside the parenthesis or don't use parenthesis if there is only 1 argument. For example:- const Greet = props => {} should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
const Greet = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    return <h1>Aloha you nutter! How's it going {props.name}?</h1>}

export default Greet
```

Props is params in arrow function.

Comment: Thank you all for your help :-)